# pascal file of array and file to array

Tags: arrays, file, pascal

I am a begineer in pascal programming so I really hope for a help ;)

so I want to make a program that can create a file consist of array, and that array can be used as parameter for any procedure in later.
here the code I made for creating that file:

```
type
item = record
    d:string;
    t:integer;
    n:string;
   end;

Ar = array[1..max] of item;
f = file of Ar;

var
i,n =integer;
begin
read(n);
assign(f, datafilm.dat);
append(f);
for i:=1 to n do
   begin
   readln(Ar[i].n);
   readln(Ar[i].t);
   readln(Ar[i].d);
   i:=i+1;
end;
close(f);
end.
```

and for the later use, for example:

```
if Ar[i].d=1 then begin end;
```

is that correct??

and if I want to assign a file as array how to separate one from another array? if from example I have a file that consist of long sentence 1, long sentence 2, and long sentence 3 into a different array???

thank you in advance!!

Comment: You declared `Ar[i].d` as a `string`, so comparing it to the integer `1` is not going to be valid (type mismatch). Regarding working with files, have you gone through any tutorials or read parts of a book covering Pascal file I/O? If you declare, `f = file of xxx`, then when you read or write the file, it expects a single item that is of type `xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

Was this assigned by a teacher?  They are doing you a disservice by using a filing system that became obsolete with Delphi 1. Assuming this is dos TP (with fixed size strings) the problem is just comparing a string to a number.  so use StrToInt(ar[i].d] or ar[i].d='1';